# Random number generation using t-distribution or laplace distribution

Tags: distributions, matlab, random-generation, t-distribution, laplace-distribution

I am a newbie in stat. I am completing my thesis in [Evolutionary algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm). I have to generate some random numbers from [T-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) or [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution). How can I do this?

An easy and simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to implement in matlab

Comment: @cruc Matlab has an inverse t distribution: see http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/tinv.html .  All you do is apply this function to a uniform random variate in the range (0,1).

Comment: As `tinv` is part of the Statistics toolbox, you'd have to pay extra for this, unless you are eligible for a student version, in which case it comes as part of the package.

Comment: **Quick and dirty**: `sqrt(n)*randn(1)/norm(randn(n,1))` will generate a $t$-distributed variate with $n$ degrees of freedom. This is probably the fastest to code, but certainly not the fastest to execute, especially if you need a very large number of them.

Comment: Not quite sure why you bothered to ask about Laplace distribution, as it explicitly tells you how to generate these in the link you give in your question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to do this in Matlab using [TINV](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/tinv.html) from that statistics toolbox:

```
%# choose the degree of freedom
df = 4; %# note you can also choose an array of df's if necessary

%# create a vector of 100,000 uniformly distributed random varibles
uni = rand(100000,1);

%# look up the corresponding t-values
out = tinv(uni,df);
```

With a more recent version of Matlab, you can also simply use [TRND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/trnd.html) to create the random numbers directly.

```
out = trnd(100000,df);
```

Here's the histogram of `out` [image]

**EDIT Re:merged question**

Matlab has no built-in function for drawing numbers from a Laplace distribution. However, there is the function [LAPRND](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13705-laplacian-random-number-generator) from the Matlab File Exchange that provides a well-written implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Easy answer: Use R and get `n` variables for a $t$-distribution with `df` degrees of freedom by `rt(n, df)`. If you don't use R, maybe you can write what language you use, and others may be able to tell precisely what to do.

If you don't use R or another language with a built in random number generator for the $t$-distribution, but you have access to the *quantile function*, $Q$, for the $t$-distribution and you can generate a uniform random variable $U$ on $[0,1]$ then $Q(U)$ follows a $t$-distribution.

Else take a look at [this brief section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Monte_Carlo_sampling) in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. I want to do it in matlab. I may have to use t-distribution with degrees of freedom ranging from 1 to 30. In wiki, formula for only 1, 2, 4 degrees of freedom is given. Is there any generalized formula for quantile function? Could you give formulas for other even number of degrees of freedom?

Comment: @crucified, no closed form will exist for the $t$ quantile function. See the G. W. Hill references listed [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/TDist.html). You could also get the source code for [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) and look up the [appropriate functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-t_002ddistribution.html). I haven't looked myself, but it's probably easy enough to port to MATLAB.

Comment: @cardinal +1, especially given the fact that there exist GSL bindings for Octave.

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the Wikipedia article, I've written a function to generate random variables from the Laplace dsistribution. Here it is:

```
function x = laplacernd(mu,b,sz)
%LAPLACERND Generate Laplacian random variables 
% 
%  x = LAPLACERND(mu,b,sz) generates random variables from a Laplace
%  distribution having parameters mu and b. sz stands for the size of the
%  returned random variables. See [1] for Laplace distribution.
% 
%  [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution
% 
%  by Ismail Ari, 2011

if nargin < 1 % Equal to exponential distribution scaled by 1/2
    mu = 0;
end
if nargin < 2
    b = 1;
end
if nargin < 3
    sz = 1;
end

u = rand(sz) - 0.5;
x = mu - b*sign(u) .* log(1-2*abs(u));
```

And here is a code snippet to use it

```
clc, clear
mu = 30;
b = 2;
sz = [50000 1];

x = laplacernd(mu,b,sz);
hist(x,100)
```

[image: Laplace distribution]

Answer (score 4):

The best (fastest to run, not fastest to code;) free solution I have found in Matlab was to wrap R's MATHLIB_STANDALONE c library with a mex function. This gives you access to R's t-distribution PRNG. One advantage of this approach is that you also can use the same trick to get variates from a non-central t distribution.

The second best free solution was to use octave's implementation of [trnd](https://web.archive.org/web/20111128092345/http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Random-Number-Generation.html)$^\dagger$. Porting from octave turned out to be more work than wrapping c code for me.

For my tastes, using uniform generation via `rand` and inverting via `tinv` was much too slow. YMMV.

---

$^\dagger$ New [link](https://docs.octave.org/interpreter/Random-Number-Generation.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same approach that was described in response to your question about generating  random numbers from a t-distribution. First generate uniformly distributed random numbers from (0,1) and then apply the inverse cumulative distribution function of the Laplace distribution, which is given in the Wikipedia article you linked to.

Comment: **NB:** This is a reply to a second question that was subsequently merged with the present one.  As @mark999 correctly points out here, the two questions are the same except one asks for Laplace variates and the original (this one) asks for Student t variates.

Comment: @whuber: it might make sense, then, to edit this question to include the Laplace distribution.